# jQuery Pause Between Animation And Color Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the div to `fadeOut()`, then when it's not visible to change the color and text, and then but only then, reappear.
**Here's the code**

```
var changeColor = function() {
     var div = document.getElementById("div");
     var p = document.getElementById("p");
     var pText = p.innerHTML;
     if (pText == "Click Me!") {
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#div").fadeToggle("fast");
     }, function() {
         $("#div").css("background-color", "aquamarine");
         p.innerHTML = "More!";
     }, function() {
         $("#div").fadeToggle("fast");
     });
     } else if (pText == "More!") {
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#div").fadeToggle("fast");
     }, function() {
         $("#div").css("background-color", "coral");
         p.innerHTML = "Click Me!";
     }, function() {
         $("#div").fadeToggle("fast");
     });
     } else {
         return;
     }
    }
```

This is the link to codepen.io, the project [My Project](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbJdXe)

Comment: You need to use callbacks if you want sequential animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNeyNg) - Change the javascript to the following:

```
  var changeColor = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var p = document.getElementById("p");
    var pText = p.innerHTML;
    if (pText == "Click Me!") {
        $("#div").fadeToggle("fast", function(){
          $("#div").css("background-color", "aquamarine");
          $("#div").fadeToggle("slow");
          p.innerHTML = "More!";
        });
    } else if (pText == "More!") {
        $("#div").fadeOut("fast", function(){
          $("#div").css("background-color", "color");
          $("#div").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

**Explanation:**

Functions like fadeToggle can take a callback function which triggers after the animation is complete:

```
$("#div").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    /*code here will trigger after animation is complete*/
});
```

Comment: You don't need to call $("#div") so many times, jQuery is chainable. if you don't want to chain then cache the result as a varialbe

Comment: @Saar you mean like `var div = $("#div");` then using it like this `div.fadeOut()` ?

Comment: Exactly, every time you call the jquery function you are searching the DOM which is a heavy operation

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @ImranBughio **Thank you so much!, now everything is working!**.

Comment: @Saar **Thank you for the tip also!**